# Recursive calls with Observables in Angular

Tags: angular, recursion, rxjs, observable

I have an Angular app where I want to upload a file to a content server (CS) service. Due to how this service is built, I need to also build the folders where my file will be finally uploaded.

So, for example, if I want my file to be uploaded into /base/1/2/3, I will check if /base/1/2/3 is created in the CS; if not, I keep checking /base/1/2, /base/1 and /base. If only /base is created, then I will create /base/1, then /base/1/2, then /base/1/2/3 and then I will upload my file.

I'm trying to do this with Observables and recursively, but I can´t make it work. I know about operator expand for recursion, but I think it's not what I need.

I have a [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/ORtD6LKICglkVNHfsGgB) where I'm simulating the http calls with delay(1000).
Checking recursively if a path exists works, but then when I start to build the path only the first one works, then nothing.

This is my code, a basic component

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <button (click)="build()">BUILD!</button>
    </div>
  `
})
export class AppComponent { 

  constructor(private service: AppService) {}

  build() {
    this.service
      .build('base', ['1', '2', '3'])
      .subscribe(data => console.log('done!'));
  }

}
```

and this is the service

```
@Injectable()
export class AppService {

  constructor() {}

  build(name: string, path: string[]): Observable<any> {
    return this.buildRec(name, path || []);
  }

  buildRec(name: string, path: string[], folder: string): Observable<any> {
    const fullpath = !path.length ? name : `${name}/${path.join('/')}`;

    return this.getBasePath(fullpath)
      .flatMap(data => {
        console.log(`found ${fullpath} with id ${data}`);
        return this.createFolder(folder, data);
      })
      .catch(err => {
        const newFolder = path.pop()
        console.log(`not found ${fullpath}`);
        return this.buildRec(name, path, newFolder)
          flatMap(data => {
            return this.createFolder(folder, data);
          });
      });
  }

  getBasePath(path: string): Observable<any> {
    return path === 'base' ? Observable.of('1').delay(1000) : Observable.throw('error').delay(1000);
  }

  createFolder(folder: string, id: string): Observable<any> {
    console.log(`creating folder ${folder}`);
    return Observable
      .of(folder)
      //.map(res => console.log(`created ${res}`)
      .delay(1000);
  }
}
```

The output should be something like this:

not found base/1/2/3
not found base/1/2
not found base/1
found base with id 1
creating folder 1
creating folder 2
creating folder 3
done!

but after `creating folder` 1 it goes to `done!`

Does anyone know how to get this to work?
Regards

Comment: I think you should use `unshift()` instead of `pop()` to build the path in the right order

Comment: sorry, this was actually working, it was a problem with one of my services that was returning an error and I was not caching it.